# Solving for positive semidefiniteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, hilbert-spaces

Given a real matrix M, is there a matrix function f(M) such that $f(M)-M$ is guaranteed to be positive semidefinite, other than the idea of multiplying $M$ with its transpose and apart from the trivial case where $f(M)=M$? If so, what would $f(.)$ be?

Comment: Do you really mean $f(M)-M$?

Comment: Indeed, one had might as well ask for $g$ such that $g(M)$ is positive semidefinite, where $g(x) = f(x)-x$.

Comment: Yes, the matrix returned by, $g(M) = f(M)-M$ has to be p.s.d.

Comment: Then do not forget the trivial case: $f(M)=M$.

Comment: well..thanks- excluded the trivial case in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many such functions, such as $M+\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{k=0}^na_k(g_i(M)^Tg_i(M))^k$ with arbitrary matrix functions $g_i$ and arbitrary nonnegative coefficients $a_k$, but I cannot recall any well known ones.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on user Helms Answer: Let $M$ be diagonalizable and $M=A\Lambda A^{-1}$ for some invertible $A$ and $\Lambda$ as $M$'s eigenvalues. Let $f(M)$ be some polynomial function of $M$. Then
\begin{align}
f(M)-M=A(f(\Lambda)-\Lambda)A^{-1}
\end{align}
Thus positive definiteness of $f(M)-M$ will only come from the same of $f(\Lambda)-\Lambda$ which for a given eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $M$ corresponds to $f(\lambda)-\lambda > 0$. Thus, every polynomial function $f(x)$ such that $g(x)=f(x)-x$ is positive for $x=\lambda_i,~\forall i=1,2,..,N$ is a candidate for your function. Here $\lambda_i$ denotes eigenvalues of $M$.

Answer (score 1):

The following is useful, if the matrix is diagonalizable, and the idea is applied to the eigenvalues. Then ...

...any function $f(x)$ shall do, which has that $f(x)>x$ . The most simple one is $f(x)=x+1$ . so if $f(M) = M + I$ where $I$ is the identity should suffice. 
You could also use $f(M) = M^2 + 2*I$ or $f(M) = \cosh(M)+ I$ where $\cosh(.)$ is the power series, which takes also matrices as arguments.

Comment: Can you kindly expand on this statement 'The following is useful, if the matrix is diagonalizable, and the idea is applied to the eigenvalues' ? I am missing out the point.

Comment: Well, if I take an argument involving the concept of "eigenvalues", then a matrix needs to have such "eigenvalues" (= must be "diagonalizable"). I was not sure, whether the given idea (adapted) also applies to arbitrary matrices - but now I see, that your question concerning "positive semidefiniteness" already implies this, so that remark could be removed...

Comment: Surely you meant "orthogonally diagonalizable".